# configure kubelet to use rkt instead of docker on coreos

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, rkt, kubelet

I'm trying to deploy master node as described in https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-master.html
on CoreOS beta (1153.4.0).

I'm using the following kubeconfig yaml file:

```
 current-context: tuxin-coreos-context
 apiVersion: v1
 clusters:
 - cluster:
     certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
     server: https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443
   name: tuxin-coreos-cluster
 contexts:
 - context:
     cluster: tuxin-coreos-cluster
   name: tuxin-coreos-context
 kind: Config
 preferences:
   colors: true
 users:
 - name: ufk
   user:
     client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.pem
     client-key: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
```

I'm using `KUBELET_VERSION` v1.4.0-beta.10_coreos.0

`systemctl cat kubelet` returns the following:

## /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/manifests
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/containers

Environment=KUBELET_VERSION=v1.4.0-beta.10_coreos.0
Environment="RKT_OPTS=--volume var-log,kind=host,source=/var/log \
  --mount volume=var-log,target=/var/log \
  --volume dns,kind=host,source=/etc/resolv.conf \
  --mount volume=dns,target=/etc/resolv.conf"

ExecStart=/usr/lib/coreos/kubelet-wrapper \
  --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig  \
  --network-plugin-dir=/etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d   \
  --network-plugin=cni   \
  --register-schedulable=false   \
  --allow-privileged=true  \
  --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests   \
  --hostname-override=coreos-2.tux-in.com   \
  --container-runtime=rkt
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`journalctl -b -u kubelet` returns

```
Sep 26 17:58:53 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: Starting kubelet.service...
Sep 26 17:58:53 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: Started kubelet.service.
Sep 26 17:58:53 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[1725]: image: using image from file /usr/lib64/rkt/stage1-images/stage1-fly.aci
Sep 26 17:58:54 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[1725]: image: using image from local store for image name quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.4.0-beta.10_coreos.0
Sep 26 17:59:11 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[1725]: W0926 17:59:11.807917    1725 server.go:383] No API client: no api servers specified
Sep 26 17:59:12 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[1725]: I0926 17:59:12.871488    1725 manager.go:140] cAdvisor running in container: "/system.slice/kubelet.service"
Sep 26 17:59:14 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[1725]: I0926 17:59:14.454499    1725 fs.go:116] Filesystem partitions: map[/dev/sda9:{mountpoint:/var/lib/docker major:8 minor:9 fsType:ext4 blockSize:0} /dev/sda3:{mountpoint:/etc/ssl/certs major:8 minor:3 fsType:ext4 blockSize:0} overlay:{mountpoint:/ major:0 minor:54 fsType:overlay blockSize:0}]
Sep 26 17:59:14 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[1725]: I0926 17:59:14.458559    1725 manager.go:195] Machine: {NumCores:8 CpuFrequency:3060000 MemoryCapacity:4145504256 MachineID:f3e41f31b6024d84806ddf3a54075add SystemUUID:00000000-0000-0000-0000-1C6F653E6F72 BootID:ca4acb17-baa6-4863-acdb-2db06609b0d8 Filesystems:[{Device:/dev/sda3 Capacity:1031946240 Type:vfs Inodes:260096 HasInodes:true} {Device:overlay Capacity:984373800960 Type:vfs Inodes:61054976 HasInodes:true} {Device:/dev/sda9 Capacity:113819422720 Type:vfs Inodes:28536576 HasInodes:true}] DiskMap:map[8:0:{Name:sda Major:8 Minor:0 Size:120034123776 Scheduler:cfq} 8:16:{Name:sdb Major:8 Minor:16 Size:1000204886016 Scheduler:cfq} 8:32:{Name:sdc Major:8 Minor:32 Size:3000592982016 Scheduler:cfq} 8:48:{Name:sdd Major:8 Minor:48 Size:2000398934016 Scheduler:cfq} 8:64:{Name:sde Major:8 Minor:64 Size:1000204886016 Scheduler:cfq}] NetworkDevices:[{Name:enp4s0 MacAddress:1c:6f:65:3e:6f:72 Speed:1000 Mtu:1500} {Name:flannel.1 MacAddress:6a:5e:8b:1d:00:17 Speed:0 Mtu:1450}] Topology:[{Id:0 Memory:4145504256 Cores:[{Id:0 Threads:[0 4] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:1 Threads:[1 5] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:2 Threads:[2 6] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:3 Threads:[3 7] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]}] Caches:[{Size:8388608 Type:Unified Level:3}]}] CloudProvider:Unknown InstanceType:Unknown InstanceID:None}
Sep 26 17:59:14 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[1725]: I0926 17:59:14.459359    1725 manager.go:201] Version: {KernelVersion:4.7.1-coreos ContainerOsVersion:CoreOS 1153.4.0 (MoreOS) DockerVersion:1.11.2 CadvisorVersion: CadvisorRevision:}
Sep 26 17:59:14 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[1725]: W0926 17:59:14.460736    1725 server.go:613] No api server defined - no events will be sent to API server.
Sep 26 17:59:14 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[1725]: I0926 17:59:14.460794    1725 kubelet.go:255] Adding manifest file: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
Sep 26 17:59:14 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[1725]: W0926 17:59:14.463983    1725 kubelet_network.go:64] Hairpin mode set to "promiscuous-bridge" but container runtime is "rkt", ignoring
Sep 26 17:59:14 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[1725]: I0926 17:59:14.464034    1725 kubelet.go:516] Hairpin mode set to "none"
Sep 26 17:59:14 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[1725]: Error: failed to run Kubelet: failed to create kubelet: cannot find rkt binary: exec: "rkt": executable file not found in $PATH
Sep 26 17:59:14 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[1725]: failed to run Kubelet: failed to create kubelet: cannot find rkt binary: exec: "rkt": executable file not found in $PATH
Sep 26 17:59:14 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 26 17:59:14 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 26 17:59:14 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 26 17:59:24 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 26 17:59:24 coreos-2.tux-in.com systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet.service.
```

I tried to specify specific path to rkt, I tried to the same path that I have it on my core os which is `/bin/rkt` but it can't find the binary there. is the hypercube image is missing the rkt binary for some reason?

## update

ok I tried to debug this issue further but got to a dead end again.

I tried to run everything manually to see where's the problem..

so I set the following environment variables:

```
export KUBELET_VERSION=v1.4.0_coreos.0
export RKT_OPTS=--volume var-log,kind=host,source=/var/log \
 --mount volume=var-log,target=/var/log \
 --volume dns,kind=host,source=/etc/resolv.conf \
 --mount volume=dns,target=/etc/resolv.conf
```

then I copied `/usr/lib/coreos/kubelet-wrapper` file to my home directory and modified it to run bash instead:

```
...
${KUBELET_ACI}:${KUBELET_VERSION} --exec=/bin/bash
```

then I ran kubelet with the following parameters:

```
./kubelet-wrapper   --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig    --network-plugin-dir=/etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d     --network-plugin=cni     --register-schedulable=false     --allow-privileged=true    --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests     --hostname-override=coreos-2.tux-in.com     --container-runtime=rkt
```

then after getting a bash prompt, I ran `kubelet` with the following parameters:

```
./kubelet --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig  \
  --network-plugin-dir=/etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d   \
  --network-plugin=cni   \
  --register-schedulable=false   \
  --allow-privileged=true  \
  --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests   \
  --hostname-override=coreos-2.tux-in.com   \
  --container-runtime=rkt
```

and I got again the `cannot find rkt binary` error message.
I tried finding `rkt` binary in that container by running `find / | grep rkt$` but no rkt binary found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to setup kubernetes with rkt as the runtime is to use the scripts found [here](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/tree/master/multi-node/generic). As Rob stated, the reason you see that error is because the kubelet is being run inside a container and doesn't see the `/usr/bin/rkt` on the host.

Right now, getting the containerized kubelet to properly talk to the rkt runtime on the host is a little complicated. Just just bind-mounting the rkt binary into the kubelet container is not enough. The details are captured in this [PR](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/pull/551/commits).

We've spent some effort making this all work smoothly in the coreos-kubernetes repo and testing the result. If you use the scripts in that repository things should just work by setting the `CONTAINER_RUNTIME` environment variable to `rkt`.

Answer (score 1):

Right now the manual process is a little bit tricky to swap docker for rkt, but the automated scripts in the [coreos-kubernetes](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes) such as the `kube-aws` tool or the Vagrant docs do this well.

In your specific circumstance, the rkt binary needs to be mounted into the wrapper with `RKT_OPTS` from the host (this means it gets updated automatically), and then you'll need to add a few more flags to the API server:

`--container-runtime=rkt`

`--rkt-api-endpoint=HOST:PORT`

`--rkt-path=PATH_TO_RKT_BINARY`

`--rkt-stage1-image=STAGE1`

CoreOS is intending to ship better manual instructions over time as the debugging process and best practices for rkt + kubernetes get more clear.